# Using this regex, why does it only capture the last list item

Tags: javascript, c++, regex

Using the regex:

```
(?:(?:(x),)*)
```

to match a list string for example:

x,x,x,x,

I only get one capture group, holding the last x. **How can i get a capture group for each x.**

The regex is a simplification. X represent a long regex expression

*I'm using regexes in C++, vs11 (ECMAScript ~=javascript).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `group` with `*` quantifier..

First `x,` matches in group 1..It again matches `x,` which **overwrites** the group value..It does this till the last match..

You can instead use `(x,)` **without** `*` quantifier to match the text **individually**

---

**NOTE**

Only **.NET** supports multiple group value captures using [capturecollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection.aspx)..i.e it would capture `x,x,x,x,` with `(x,)*` regex

Comment: This forced me to tear my overlong regex apart. which has only helped me in the long term!